# Scan for broken image references in CSS?

Tags: css, http-status-code-404, background-image

I have a very large site to audit ( was not really made by a good developer). I have found quite a few references to images that don't exist within css.

For example:

```
#element-id:after {
background: url("/path-to-broken-image.jpg");
}
```

My issue is, these broken images are only showing in Safari (where they show a box with question mark in the center), and it's quite a large site to go through page by page.

Does anyone know of a way that I could scan the site and find all the broken references?

Thanks

Comment: This Code Work on a Server, You Can Try to use a server Example Wamp Or xampp

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. The file doesn't exist, so it's not a server issue. I'm trying to scan for broken image references in CSS.

Comment: background: url("/path-to-broken-image.jpg"); this code '/' indicate a base url and then root then a image in a root.